# How to fill a progressBar holding a button during 2 seconds?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-progressbar

I would like to show and fill a progressBar pressing and holding a button. I would like the progressBar is being filled progressively while the user hold the button and execute a method when the progressBar is completed.

I also would like the progressBar is reset to 0 and hidden if the user release the button before to complete the progressBar.

I have tried the next code, but it doesn´t work. When the user presses and hold the button the progressBar appears and it dissapear when the button is released, but the progressBar doesn´t progresses, it´s empty all the time.

Thanks a lot in advance, I hope someone can help me.

```
private void pressBtnAnswer() {

        btnAnswer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //when button is pressed
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {

                    //show the progressBar
                    progressBarAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                    new CountDownTimer(2000, 500) {

                        //if button still pressed add 25% to progressBar
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            if(btnAnswer.isPressed()){
                                progressBarAnswer.setProgress(progressBarAnswer.getProgress()+25);
                            }

                        }

                        //after 2 seconds reset the progressBar, hide it and run showAnswer method
                        public void onFinish() {
                            if(btnAnswer.isPressed()){
                                progressBarAnswer.setProgress(0);
                                progressBarAnswer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                showAnswer();
                            }
                        }
                    }.start();


                //if button is released reset progressBar and hide it
                }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    progressBarAnswer.setProgress(0);
                    progressBarAnswer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it deleting the verifications btnAnswer.isPressed

But a new problem appeared. The CountDownTimer didn´t stop when the user released the button.

Finally I solved it creating the CountDownTimer out of method and creating methods to start it and cancel it.

```
CountDownTimer cTimer = null;
```

```
//start timer function
    void startTimer() {
        cTimer = new CountDownTimer(2000, 200) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                progressBarAnswer.setProgress(progressBarAnswer.getProgress() + 10);
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                progressBarAnswer.setProgress(0);
                progressBarAnswer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                showAnswer();
            }
        };
        cTimer.start();
    }

    //cancel timer
    void cancelTimer() {
        if(cTimer!=null)
            cTimer.cancel();
    }
```

And this is the method for the button:

```
private void pressBtnAnswer() {

        btnAnswer.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                //when button is pressed
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    double moneyOnTheTable = Double.parseDouble(tvMoneyOnTheTable.getText().toString().replaceAll(",", "."));

                    if (moneyOnTheTable < 0.004) {
                        Toast.makeText(SuccessErrorGameActivity.this, "La apuesta no puede ser 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                        //show the progressBar
                        progressBarAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        startTimer();

                    }
                } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    progressBarAnswer.setProgress(0);
                    progressBarAnswer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    cancelTimer();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```